# Problems with \ref when using soul for highlighting

Tags: cross-referencing, color, soul

Here is a minimal example showing the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{soul}
%\soulregister{\ref}{1}
\begin{document}

\section*{x}\label{x}

\section*{y}
\hl{ Some text.
  Section~\ref{x}.
}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the error

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `{x}' on page 0 undefined on input line 12.

! Argument of \ref has an extra }.
```

The problem is with `\ref`. Commenting out the line beginning with "Subsection" makes the error disappear. `\soulregister` is intended for font commands. I don't know if `\ref` is a font command, but I could not get `\soulregister` to fix the problem (see the commented line above).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Enclosing the `\ref{x}` in `{ }` works. `soul` then takes it as one element instead of breaking it up, I guess. It seems to me that it reads both `\ref` and `{x}` in two steps and sets it together again while adding another set of braces, i.e. the result is `\ref{{x}}`. This doesn't matter much for font commands but `\ref` takes the inner braces as part of the label name. This causes the warning about the unknown label. The error is caused because `\ref` is then also expanded by `soul` inside a `{ }` group, i.e. `{\ref}`. Don't ask me why.

Note that you can't label a `\section*` because it doesn't has a number.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{soul}
%\soulregister{\ref}{1}
\begin{document}

\section{x}\label{x}

\section{y}
\hl{ Some text.
   Section~{\ref{x}}.
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Can you explain why my version failed, and why the extra brackets fix it? I take it `\ref` is not a font command then?

Comment: @Faheem: See my recent edit. `\ref` is not a font command. It doesn't change the font.

Comment: Is it worth reporting this as a bug?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I would check the documentation first if this is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: To answer your other question from the chat: `\textit{...}` works because `soul` detects `\textit` and then handles its argument correctly. However, if you use `{\itshape ...}` then there is no argument which can be handled in a special way.

Comment: Is there a way of writing a macro that will handle \cite and \ref properly?  I've found that even the extra '{}' sometimes seems to fail in large projects. And obviously it's a real annoyance to have to edit the main text in large documents to make a certain macro work.

Comment: Ahah! I have found the issue in my large project - {\cite{x0}} works, but {\cite{x0,x1}} doesn't - ie citation of more than one ref at a time breaks it.

Comment: I can't get citation to work at all. `\hl{This is a citation of {\cite{ljung_system_1999}}.}` raises `Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed. ...citation of {\cite{ljung_system_1999}}.}`