# How to highlight citations in a revised manuscript

Tags: highlighting

I am submitting a revised manuscript to a journal (Medical Physics), and the journal requires that changes that are made in the revised manuscript should be highlighted.  I've been attempting to use the soul package with the \hl command, but it seems that there is a known bug where you can't highlight citations.  (You get a compilation error.)  I have found some [workarounds](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23307/problems-with-ref-when-using-soul-for-highlighting), but they don't seem to work for multiple citations like this: \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.
Also, the workarounds seem ugly, and I don't want to submit a latex file contaminated with ugly hacks for highlighting that the editors will not understand.

How do people handle this?  It must be a common issue.

Should I just highlight the pdf using Adobe Acrobat and then submit a highlighted version of the pdf along with my latex file?  I'm not sure that the journal will accept that -- they may want to receive just one manuscript that has the highlighting built in, rather than a manuscript and a separate pdf with highlighting.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[aapm,graphicx,preprint,showkeys]{revtex4-1} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\hl{This text is highlighted}.

Here's a citation \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.

%\hl{ Highlighting a citation causes a compilation error \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}. }

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{rockafellar1997convex}
R.T. Rockafellar.
\newblock {\em Convex analysis}.
\newblock Number~28. Princeton university press, 1997.

\bibitem{rudin1992nonlinear}
L.~Rudin, S.~Osher, and E.~Fatemi.
\newblock Nonlinear total variation based noise removal algorithms.
\newblock {\em Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena}, 60(1):259--268, 1992.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pragmatic solution: Just use another, less fragile sort of highlighting, e.g., text color: `\renewcommand{\hl}[1]{\color{red}#1}`.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, very helpful.  This command seems to change the color of all text in the manuscript after the command is given.  Do I also need a separate command to switch back to the normal text color?  Would you mind submitting an answer to show exactly how you would fix the MWE?

Comment: @Daniel There should be a pair of braces to limit the effect of `\color`: `\renewcommand{\hl}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}`.

Comment: @gernot: Upps, you're right of course. Hasty comments :-)

Comment: @littleO: Added corrected version as an answer

Comment: Comment as I don't have time to test: I've used `ulem` rather than `soul` for this, and underlined the changes.  I didn't have any trouble with (numeric superscripted) citations. Underline may be ugly but that means it's not used for anything else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know your other reasons for using the `soul` package, but doesn't the `xcolor` package suffice? Moreover, if I read the author's instructions correctly, you can also choose to use just a different text color.

Here are some possibilities for highlighting. Changing the background color usually entails some limitations, like boxes that don't wrap or restrictions on what can be put inside the highlighted area; but citations work with all approaches.

```
\documentclass[aapm,graphicx,preprint,showkeys]{revtex4-1} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\hl[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand\hlbreakable[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{highlighted}{colback=yellow,coltext=red,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\hl{This text is highlighted.}

\hl{Highlighting a citation causes no compilation error \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.}

\hlbreakable{Highlighting a citation causes no compilation error \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.
\lipsum}

\begin{highlighted}
Highlighting a citation causes no compilation error \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.
\lipsum
\end{highlighted}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{rockafellar1997convex}
  R.T. Rockafellar.
  \newblock {\em Convex analysis}.
  \newblock Number~28. Princeton university press, 1997.
\bibitem{rudin1992nonlinear}
  L.~Rudin, S.~Osher, and E.~Fatemi.
  \newblock Nonlinear total variation based noise removal algorithms.
  \newblock {\em Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena}, 60(1):259--268, 1992.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

> [image]
> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]
>
> [image]

**Edit:** It may be more convenient to define the `\hlbreakable` command as an environment, since `\begin`-`\end` pairs are easier to trace than pairs of braces.

```
\newenvironment{hlbreakable}%
  {\color{red}}%
  {}
...
\begin{hlbreakable}
Highlighting a citation causes no compilation error \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.
\lipsum
\end{hlbreakable}
```

Comment: `\colorbox`es cannot wrap, can they?

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but I agree with @Daniel's comment that \colorboxes can't wrap.  Suppose that I want to highlight an entire paragraph.  What would be a nice way to do that?

Comment: Thank you.  Would you mind providing an example that shows your first suggestion: "Either don't use background color and replace \textcolor by the \color declaration" ?

Comment: Also, how would you remove the black border around the highlighted text?

Comment: Thank you, that was super helpful!  "Moreover, if I read the author's instructions correctly, you can also choose to use just a different text color."  I think this is the simplest solution for my situation, together with the \hlbreakable command you provided.

Comment: @littleO This is decribed in the docs of the `tcolorbox` package. Or look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247509/110998): add the options `boxrule=0pt,frame hidden`.

Comment: @littleO Btw, the `\hlbreakable` command is essentially the same as Daniel's `\hl` command (if you add the extra braces to delimit the scope of the `\color` command).

Comment: @littleO Better use an `hlbreakable` environment instead of a command if you want to highlight large areas. See the last edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: None of these solutions really work. Footnotes are ignored, \{hl} does not wrap

Comment: From your minimal rant it is hard to guess what's going wrong. Yes, `\hl` does not wrap, as I also write in my intro, but wrapping was not the point of the original question. Regarding footnotes, it maybe depends on the class you are using. With 'normal' classes, footnotes worked in my tests just now. `revtex` seems to treat footnotes differently, so there might be some interference. Best ask a separate question, and please provide a minimal example such your setting is clear.

Answer (score 15):

You only need the "soul" and "color" packages for this to work. Inside the "\hl{...}" command, instead of just putting in "\cite{...}", type "\mbox{\cite{...}}". This should do it.

Without the color/xcolor it will only underline instead of adding the yellow background.

Comment: You should post a minimal document showing whether this works for multiple citations.

Comment: Upvoted this because it is the only response that works with \hl

Comment: Although this isn't throwing the compilation error, the highlight changes from yellow background to a simple underlined version..

Comment: Okay, we need both soul as well as color package for the yellow background to work. Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

A pragmatic solution would be to use some other, less intrusive implementation of highlighting. In the following, I define the `\hl` command to just switch the text color to red (slightly toned for better readability):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\hl[1]{%
  \bgroup
  \hskip0pt\color{red!80!black}%
  #1%
  \egroup
}

\begin{document}

\hl{This text is highlighted}.

Here's a citation \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.

\hl{ Highlighting a citation does no longer cause a compilation error and even  works across line breaks \cite{rockafellar1997convex,rudin1992nonlinear}.}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{rockafellar1997convex}
R.T. Rockafellar.
\newblock {\em Convex analysis}.
\newblock Number~28. Princeton university press, 1997.

\bibitem{rudin1992nonlinear}
L.~Rudin, S.~Osher, and E.~Fatemi.
\newblock Nonlinear total variation based noise removal algorithms.
\newblock {\em Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena}, 60(1):259--268, 1992.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This simple approach looks less fancy, but has a lot of advantages: It works over most content (headings, tables, formulas, ...), is more printer-friendly and – taking the viewpoint of the reviewer – a lot more friendly for the reviewer's eye.

Comment: +1 though red often comes out black on monochrome printers so another colour might work better (you can't assume your reviewer will work on screen or have easy access to a colour printer)

Comment: A downvote about a year later? I wonder what was the reason for that...

Comment: Anyway to make it incorporate footnotes? PS citations don't work for me.