# Error: Reconstruction failed for \hl (highlighted) newcommand text

Tags: macros, highlighting, soul, emphasis

Sorry if this has been asked before. I could not find an answer to this problem yet. I'm finding some issues when highlighting text defined by newcommand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\newcommand{\etal}{\emph{et al.}}
\begin{document}
\hl{A statement \etal}
\end{document}
```

gives error `Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.`

Surprisingly, `\hl{A statement \emph{et al.}}` works just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I can do to fix this? Using `\emph{et al.}` instead of `\etal` is not my preferred solution, since sometimes I just want to highlight text that's already there. 
[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23307/problems-with-ref-when-using-soul-for-highlighting) doesn't solve the problem either, since `\hl{A statement {\etal}}` returns the same error. I've checked [this other solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in/139500#139500), but I'm not sure how to use it for my own defined command...

Thanks!

Comment: \soulregister\etal7 works for me...

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know you could add the 7 to whatever command, even if self-defined!

Comment: the `7` is a hidden feature of `soul`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `soul` analyzes the macro arguments of `\hl` and the related `soul` macros. All font switching macros like `\emph` and `\bf` (the later being outdated, of course) are 'registered' to prevent `soul` to analyze them but to execute them immediately ('expand') in order to perform the highlighting after this expansion.

```
\hl{A statement \emph{et al.}}
```

works since `\emph` is registered already, but `\etal` is not. This can be done however with

`\soulregister\etal7`

will enable `\etal` for `soul` usage, 'abusing' the `\soulregister` feature a little bit. The documentation does not reveal that `7` is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\newcommand{\etal}{\emph{et al.}}

\soulregister{\etal}{7}
\begin{document}

\hl{A statement \emph{et al.}}


\hl{A statement \etal}
\end{document}
```

[image]