# Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed

Tags: color, soul

I already read the discussions about this error, but nothing helpfull. My MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
%\soulregister{\cl}{7} irrelevant
%\soulregister{\sethlcolor}{7}
\definecolor{inlineBG}{HTML}{F1F1F1}
\newcommand{\cl}[2]{\textcolor[HTML]{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand{\codeinline}[1]{%
  \sethlcolor{inlineBG}{%
  \texttt{\hl{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

% ok :
\codeinline{ {\cl{FF0000}{Hello}} }

% Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.
\codeinline{ {\cl{FF0000}{Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo}} }

\codeinline{ {\cl{FF0000}{Hello World}} }

\end{document}
```

the first `\codeinline` works fine, not the others. How can i fix it ?

Comment: See my answer here for a possible solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404905/31729. Don't use the `minimal`  class!

Comment: I've already try `\soulregister{\sethlcolor}{7}` same issue.

Comment: @nikopol: Your code does not reveal that you used `\soulregister`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\soulregister` isn't relevant in my mwe because the issue is the same with or without it

Comment: @nikopol: It would have been nice to add it to the question such that others do not have to suggest `\soulregister` again ... but it's your question of course.

Comment: I edit my post with `\soulregister`, no one knows?

Answer (score 8):

In a similar situation, I found the help text provided by the soul package quite useful. It suggests to wrap the text inside an mbox. Indeed, if you change your definition to

```
\newcommand{\codelinline}[1]{%
  \sethlcolor{inlineBG}{%
  \texttt{\hl{\mbox{#1}}}}%
}
```

your MWE works for me. There might be issues with hyphenation if the text inside `\codeline` is long. (Seems to be a limitation of soul generally.)

Comment: hyphenation will not work not because a limitation of soul but because there is never a line break (and so hyphenation) in a `\mbox{}`.

Comment: @Ulrike: You're right. What I meant was: with the `\mbox`, hyphenation will not work, but without the `\mbox` the soul package has problems. Actually, the help text printed by soul for the OP's error says: "I came across hyphenatable material enclosed in group braces,  which I can't handle". It's explained in §8 and §9 in section 2.1 of the soul manual.

Answer (score 5):

It won't work. The word-/syllable analyzer of soul is rather fragile and a complicated command like \textcolor throws it out of the track. If you want to color the text, you should call the color before the `\hl`. Small bit of colors can be hidden in a \mbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{inlineBG}{HTML}{F1F1F1}
\definecolor{inlineFG}   {HTML}{FF0000}
\newcommand{\codeinline}[1]{{%
  \sethlcolor{inlineBG}%
  \color{inlineFG}%
  \ttfamily
  \hl{#1}%
}}

\begin{document}

% ok :
\codeinline{Hello}

\codeinline{Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo}

\codeinline{Helloooooooooo\mbox{\textcolor{green}{oooo}}ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo}
\end{document}
```

[image]