# Using \ul{} (from soul package) with referencing labels (\nameref)

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, soul

I have this following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Introducton}
\label{sec:intro}
\blindtext{}

\section{Second Section}
\label{sec:second}

This \ul{sentence works with ``ul''}.

Reference without ``ul'': \nameref{sec:intro}

This does not work with ``ul'': \ul{\nameref{sec:intro}}.

\end{document}
```

In the document I'm working on, I'm trying to get a `\nameref{}` to be underlined using `\ul{}`, but it crashes it when I do (for some reason in this document it doesn't crash but just doesn't display). I'm using `\ul{}` because it supports line wrapping compared to `\underline{}`. I was wondering if anyone has a solution to this. Thanks.

Edit: This image is what the above code generates:
[image: Image 1]

### Attempt 1

I tried looking at similar questions and found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23308/236070), and changed `\ul{\nameref{sec:intro}}` to `\ul{{\nameref{sec:intro}}}` by adding a set of brackets, but it only replaced the missing text with a black square, as you can see here:
[image: Image 2]

### Attempt 2

As per [Robert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7674/robert)'s comment on this question, adding `\soulregister\nameref7` below `\usepackage{soul}` made no difference for me on the first image.

### Attempt 3

As per [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s comment, (1st method) `\ul{\mbox{\nameref{sec:intro}}}` does get the text to show up but does not wrap text on the document this is for.

### Attempt 4

As per [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s comment, (2nd method) Using `\underLine{\nameref{sec:intro}}` with `\usepackage{lua-ul}` and running `lualatex documentname` instead of `pdflatex documentname` in Terminal worked for me, and does wrap lines for cross-referenced text.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139500/7674) help? `\soulregister\nameref7`

Comment: @Robert It didn't change anything unfortunately...

Comment: works for me if I add that line to your example (after `\usepackage{soul}`)

Comment: you can't get a linebreak in the nameref text with soul. Either use `\ul{\mbox{\nameref{sec:intro}}}`, or use lualatex and the lua-ul package instead of soul.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Using lualatex worked for me! Would you mind making this into an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s comment, (2nd method) Using `\underLine{\nameref{sec:intro}}` with `\usepackage{lua-ul}` and running `lualatex documentname` instead of `pdflatex documentname` in Terminal worked for me, and does wrap lines for cross-referenced text